# How to idiomatically check if a Hash is not nil and so get value of a key in one line in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First I want to check for nil.
If it is not nil, then get value of key

Comment: Idiomatically, a hash is never `nil` ;-)

Comment: What is idiomatic means?

Comment: What I mean is: hashes are instances of `Hash` whereas `nil` is an instance of `NilClass`. Therefore a hash can never be `nil` and `nil` can never be a hash. They are instances of different classes. You probably want to check whether a _variable_ is `nil` or refers to a hash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A typical way would be `val = hash && hash[key]` or `val = hash[key] if hash`.

You can also use the [safe navigation operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator), like `val = hash&.dig(key)` (see [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig)) or `val = hash&.[](key)` .. I wouldn't really recommend that last one since it's not very readable

All of those examples will set `val` to nil if the hash is nil. If the key *must* exist and you want to raise an error if it doesn't, you can use `val = hash&.fetch(key)` (see [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch))